# UIActivityViewController adding Message Linkedin and Aridrop

Tags: ios, facebook, message, linkedin-api, airdrop

I have used the following code to implement UIActivityViewController.

```
UIActivityViewController *ActivityView;
NSArray *Items;
Items   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           @"A text line",
           nil];

ActivityView =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc]
 initWithActivityItems:Items applicationActivities:nil];

[ActivityView setExcludedActivityTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,nil]];

[self presentViewController:ActivityView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

In the above code when i add Facebook and Twitter accounts in the phone settings, they are shown in the UIActivityViewController. But i am not able to show Airdrop, Linkedin and Message options in th UIActivityViewController.
Is there some other specific method to implement Airdrop, Linkedin and Message along with the Facebook and Twitter in the UIActivityViewController

Comment: AirDrop should have shown for these activity items. Are you sure you are testing this on an AirDrop capable device? 
[iOS: Using AirDrop](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5887): _iPhone 5 or later, iPad (4th generation), iPad mini & iPod touch (5th generation)_